# Monitoring and limiting internet usage

Tags: software-recommendation, network

I am currently having to access the internet through a wireless dongle which is giving me a 2gb per month download allowance. I need to be really cautious about my internet usage.

Just this afternoon I ran out due to some process downloading 600mb of something. I have no idea what it was (although I suspect iTunes) or why it would need to download so much.

Is there anyway I can monitor which processes are using the network, or failing that set up a firewall that only allows the apps I choose to have access?

Answer (score 5):

If you install [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) you can monitor which application using internet. Every time any application wants to use internet you must accept or deny it, but it doesn't have an ability to measure bandwidth usage of each application.

You can see its demo [here](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/video.html).

Comment: Little Snitch is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

600 MB doesn't sound like iTunes, unless you told it to do it.

I'd look into "Software Update...", which, in its case, can have its automated run turned off so you can run it manually.

Comment: Thats the first thing I thought of as well. +1

Comment: Looks like someone down voted you, even though you're most likely correct.

Comment: Probably is correct. Isn't an answer to the question as asked, so it should probably be a comment where it might get voted up...

Comment: Well, I guess I could add it back as one *AGAIN*. It was originally a comment. At least then they can't down-vote it.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't answer my question directly, but I did look and automatic updates were switched on. So it was very useful to know!

Answer (score 3):

## [HandsOff!](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/) (trial available)

is a very feature rich firewall for MacOSX. The features included which you need are:

- prompts you when a process/applications tries to connect to the internet
- monitoring network connections
- settings rules for application's network connections

The total bandwith you see in the monitor is only since last boot.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising, onlt my Macbook rarely get's rebooted, and is often on WiFi, I would like to be able to reset the data at a point when I know I am about to use the dongle - do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @stuffle The network monitor only allows to clear the connection history, or pause monitoring.

Answer (score 3):

I found [SurplusMeter](http://www.skoobysoft.com/utilities/utilities.html) to be very effective while using my 3G USB Stick.

[image: SurplusMeter Screenshot]

Here's also a [tutorial](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/09/27/how-to-monitor-your-internet-bandwidth-usage-in-os-x-redux/).

Comment: Ooh, very good, I think a combination of this and one of the firewalls to stop software update trashing my bandwidth is likely to win the points.

Comment: Nice tool! This helped my to limit my bandwith to 300MB/month when I lived in South Africa. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try [NetUse](http://www.netuseapp.com/), $8 at the App Store.